# How to set up proxy to connect with the socket in angular

Tags: angular, socket.io, socket.io-client

Here is my code for proxy. The backend URL is https://spotlyf.in:3000 and the angular is running on http://192.168.0.169:4200.

```
{
    "/sock" : {
        "target" : "https://spotlyf.in:3000",
        "secure" : false,
        "changeOrigin" : false,
        "ws" : true
    }
}
```

Trying to connect with the socket server but continues getting this error shown below:

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /sockjs-node/129/ugqtht2m/websocket from 192.168.0.169:4200 to https://spotlyf.in:3000(ECONNRESET) 
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /sockjs-node/953/ugqtht2m/websocket from 192.168.0.169:4200 to https://spotlyf.in:3000(ECONNRESET)
```

And in console I'm getting error as shown below:

```
Get http://sock/socket.io/>EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OYMVNYK net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```